# How to avoid being prompted while deleting replicates in ggsci

Tags: shell, automation, oracle-golden-gate

I'm looking to automate the goldengate processes of stopping,deleting and adding new replicate files.This will be done in a gui which triggers a shell script in linux. While deleting the replicates it is prompting me with the following question.

GGSCI (cbl06436dat01) 1> Are you sure you want to delete all groups? Invalid response.  Must be Y or N.

I want to avoid the prompt and directly delete the replicates so I don't manually type y or n

## /bin/bash

...

./ggsci < ${GG_PATH}/delete_replicat.txt
DELETE REPLICAT *
EXIT
EOF

...

I expect to forcefully avoid the prompt (like -f in unix) and delete the replicates and move on with the script

Answer (score 0):

Please use the syntax provided by [OGG Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/non_ggsci_commands003.htm#GWURF1189):

```
cat >param.prm <<EOF
DELETE REPLICAT * EXIT
EOF
./ggsci PARAMFILE param.prm
rm param.prm
```